# Mysql Table field value as index in php array for update statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i don't get it..., i have a table `resource` with `name`, `amount` and `level`

So i created an array where i want to store the amount of resources added to each resource by level.

For example, i have ResourceA in my database with an amount of 100 and with a level 1. Because of level 1 (resourceA array index) i want to add 2 points to the amount of 100.

This is working: `WHEN 'ResourceA' THEN amount + $resourceA[1]`

This is not working: `WHEN 'ResourceA' THEN amount + $resourceA[level]`

```
$resourceA = array(0, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024);
$resourceB = array(0, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024);
$resourceC = array(0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512);

try {
   $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;port=3307;dbname=$dbname",$username, $password);

   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

   $sql = "UPDATE resource SET amount = CASE name 
               WHEN 'ResourceA' THEN amount + $resourceA[level]
               WHEN 'ResourceB' THEN amount + $resourceB[level]
               WHEN 'ResourceC' THEN amount + $resourceC[level]
               END";

    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "Updated successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
```

Can someone help me, to use the table field `level` as index of the resource-array?

**Update:** I understand why this can't working because of your explanations. Thanks for that.

I thought it would work because

```
WHEN 'ResourceA' THEN amount + $resourceA[1]
```

is working and also `amount = amount + 2` is working, then the hole string is interpreted like `WHEN 'ResourceA' THEN amount + $resourceA[1]`

Maybe there is a trick with prepared binding, that i can use level as a number in the statement.

Thanks

Comment: It's just impossible. Do you realize that SQL query is executed by SQL server, not PHP?

Comment: You either need to fetch the value of the level field into php variable and use the php variable as the index or push the resource data into a table within MySQL and use pure sql to calculate the increase by using a multi-table update syntax.

Comment: Your all right, thank you very much, maybe there is a trick with prepared binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question literally: of course, that's just **impossible**.

Because SQL won't run your PHP code. Not to mention that in the resulting SQL code there will be no PHP at all - you can check it yourself by simply echoing $sql variable out.
Likewise there is no level field value from a database while you are assembling an SQL query in your PHP script. PHP and SQL are two buildings standing opposite. You can send a letter from one to another, but you cannot write this letter in one house using a pen in another.

Luckily, for your case you don't need PHP arrays at all. Just update the fields using simple math

```
UPDATE resource SET amount = CASE name 
           WHEN 'ResourceA' THEN amount + pow(2, level)
           WHEN 'ResourceB' THEN amount + pow(2, level)
           WHEN 'ResourceC' THEN amount + pow(2, level) / 2
           END
```

In general you just have to run a separate query for each name/level combination. It's not a big deal even without prepared statements, but with them it can be done a bit cleaner

```
$update = [
    'resourceA' = array(0, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024),
    'resourceB' = array(0, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024),
    'resourceC' = array(0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512),
];
$sql = "UPDATE resource SET amount = ? WHERE name = ? AND level = ?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
foreach ($update as $name => $row)
{
    foreach ($row as $level => $value)
    {
        $stmt->execute([$value, $name, $level]);
    }
}
```

Comment: you are right and will accept your answer, but what is when i want to use other numbers? like 1,3,4,5,7. Can i get level as a variable to do what i first tried? maybe with prepared binding or with idk (select level) lvl or something with (@level := level) lvl, because THEN amount + $resourceA[1] is working